# Loop through Query and Update field

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

I'm trying to loop through a fields defined in a query to an update statement.

I have the following SQL:

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max)

@SQL= 'Select [a],[b],[c],[d],[e]....[z]
       From Table1;'
```

I want to be able to loop through all the fields [a]-[z] and update via the following statement:

```
Update Table 1 
Set [a] = Case when [a] = 'Not at all' Then 0
               when [a] = 'Very Much' Then 10 End
```

Field names are not actually [a]..[z]; I can't run the the update statement on the whole table, only a specific set of field names.

Struggling to write it programatically in SQL Server.

Comment: what have you tried so far? a cursor or while loop? if neither, I'd suggest reading this on how to write a cursor - https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-cursor/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) 
Declare @name varchar(100)
DECLARE @getid CURSOR

Set @getid = cursor for 
SELECT name 
FROM 
sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('Select [a],[b],[c],[d],[e]....[z]
   From Table1', NULL, 0)

Open @getid 
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getid INTO  @name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'Update Table1
        Set ' + @name + ' = Case when ' + @name +'= ''Very Much'' Then ''10''
        when ' +  @name + ' = ''Not at all'' Then ''0''
        Else ' + @name + ' End'

    Exec(@SQL)          
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getid INTO @name
END

CLOSE @getid
DEALLOCATE @getid
```

Basically `dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` is grabbing the fieldnames and outputting it as a recordset. Then we are just passing the the each of the records to `@name` and use it form our update statement and then executing it for each record passed.

Hope this helps someone else! Curious to see if there is a better way.

Comment: You should make an effort to be **consistent** with how you write the SQL keywords - *either* write them in all UPPERCASE (SELECT, FROM), or write them in all lowercase (cursor, for), or in mixed case (Open, Exec) - but please **pick one style** and then **stick to it** - don't mix all of them together!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to make it a little more generic I would do something like the following code.  This will allow you to not have to write the specific query for every table you want to do this to and you could potentially filter out columns you do not want in the future.

To be clear, I borrowed the SQL to do the actual UPDATE from @Dale-K post and just made it pretty.

```
DECLARE @strSQL NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @strTable NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @strColName VARCHAR(100)


SET @strTable = N'Table1'

CREATE TABLE #COLUMNS(ColName varchar(100))

SET @strSQL = ' select COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = @TableName  and DATA_TYPE in (''nvarchar'', ''varchar'')'


INSERT INTO #COLUMNS
EXEC sp_executeSQL @strSQL, N'@TableName nvarchar(100)', @TableName = @strTable


DECLARE  csrColumns  CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FOR
SELECT ColName FROM #COLUMNS

OPEN csrColumns
FETCH csrColumns INTO @strColName


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

   SET @strSQL = N'UPDATE ' + @strTable + '
        SET ' + @strColName + ' = CASE WHEN ' + @strColName +'= ''Very Much'' THEN ''10''
        WHEN ' +  @strColName + ' = ''Not at all'' THEN ''0''
        ELSE ' + @strColName + ' END'

    exec sp_ExecuteSQL @strSQL

    FETCH csrColumns INTO @strColName

END

CLOSE csrColumns
DEALLOCATE csrColumns
```